# From which place Selenium Webdriver gets title - using driver.title

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, page-title, webdriver-w3c-spec

From which place Selenium Webdriver usually gets title - using `driver.title` ?

- from Page Source
- or from DOM structure

Answer (score 0):

### title

[title](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.title) returns the title of the current page.

- Usage:

  ```
  title = driver.title
  ```
- Defination:

  ```
  def title(self):
  """Returns the title of the current page.

  :Usage:
      title = driver.title
  """
  resp = self.execute(Command.GET_TITLE)
  ```
- Details: When you invoke [`driver.title`](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#get-title) the *HTTP* **GET** *request* is invoked through the **`/session/{session id}/title`** *URI Template*.

> **NOTE**: This command returns the document title of the current top-level browsing context, equivalent to calling **`document.title`**.

- The remote end steps are:

  - If the current top-level browsing context is no longer open, return error with error code no such window.
  - Handle any user prompts and return its value if it is an error.
  - Let title be the result of calling the algorithm for getting the title attribute of the current top-level browsing context's active document.
  - Return success with data title.